How to add an environment indicator into a razor page?
I wish to add something to a razor page so that when I inspect the page code behind, I'm able to tell if it is in Production, Staging, or Development mode. In this case, I'm adding a hidden field to tell me what mode the page is in. It is not the cleanest looking code. Any ideas on a different approach to insert a status water mark of sorts into the rendered code?
@if (Env.IsProduction()) {
    <input type="hidden" name="EnvironmentName" id="EnvironmentName" value="Production" />
}
@if (Env.IsStaging())
{
    <input type="hidden" name="EnvironmentName" id="EnvironmentName" value="Staging" />
}
@if (Env.IsDevelopment())
{
    <input type="hidden" name="EnvironmentName" id="EnvironmentName" value="Development" />
}

The code behind currently looks like this:


An alternative would be to use a switch block and use a variable for value

I mean, you can do whatever you like, basically? Here’s an example that just displays the title of the current Hosting Environment by injecting IWebHostEnvironment right into the Razor page:
@page
@model MyApp.IndexModel
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment Env

<h1>@Env.EnvironmentName</h1>

That’s pretty much how it’s done in this sample from the docs: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/environments/samples/6.x/EnvironmentsSample/Pages/About.cshtml

This approach involves displaying the information on the page. I need to keep this hidden from the users.

It’s just a string, you can output it wherever you like? Maybe a title attribute or, if it really cannot be seen, a html comment. You could make a keyboard shortcut display it, or a special access-controlled endpoint if it’s really sensitive. Or just output it somewhere unobtrusive cause it’s not really that secret. Plus, support can ask users what they see, if that’s ever necessary.

You could also put it in a response header, but since you asked about Razor specifically, I imagine you want to keep it in the HTML.

Agree with the "support can ask users" comment; you can make it unobtrusive, for example putting a version number faintly in the bottom right corner of every page, and have some rule like "production system always has even numbers in the minor version"

Thanks for the feedback! Yes, I've made it a part of the displayed version # in the past. In this case, the user doesn't want any screen changes; So, I'm just trying to find the most clever way to go about it.
